# print out a separator in between different outputs for a piped xargs command

Tags: jq, xargs

I am checking properties of each output (in this case, `SecurityGroups` field of `aws ec2 describe-instances` command) from multiple outputs generated by piping into `xargs`, like so:

```
cat /tmp/ip_addresses |  xargs -I {} sh -c "aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values={} | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[]'"
```

An example output from one `aws ec2 describe-instance` call can be something like this:

```
{
  "ImageId": "ami-0d093cc932863f7a9",
  "InstanceId": "i-0b0bcbf0b766504ea",
  ...
  "IamInstanceProfile": {
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::blahblah",
    "Id": "AIPAJ4P46HO5Z322JQHWA"
  },
  ...,
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "usw2-staging-zookeeper-serv",
      "GroupId": "sg-da9361a1"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Some instances have more than 1 security group, and the outputs are not clearly separate by anything. So for 25 instances I got 28 security group objects. This makes it hard for me to distinguish which security group(s) is for which instance. Is it possible to print out a separator between each `xargs` output like a horizontal line so that I can easily tell which output(s) map to which instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various options. To add a separator as you describe, simply add it into your shell command: `; printf '---\n'`

```
cat /tmp/ip_addresses |  xargs -I {} sh -c "aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values={} | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[]'; printf '---\n'"
```

Or you could output a more structured object from the jq query: `.Reservations[].Instances[]|{InstanceId,SecurityGroups}`

```
cat /tmp/ip_addresses |  xargs -I {} sh -c "aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values={} | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[]|{InstanceId,SecurityGroups}'"
```

I don't have access to AWS to check but that should get you one object for each instance with only two fields - the InstanceId and the array of SecurityGroups.

Lastly if you want to output one object per security group but still label them with InstanceId you can do: `.Reservations[].Instances[]|{InstanceId,SecurityGroup:.SecurityGroups[]}`

```
cat /tmp/ip_addresses | xargs -I {} sh -c "aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values={} | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[]|{InstanceId,SecurityGroup:.SecurityGroups[]}'"
```